# Rdoc - a command-line tool for launching documents (improved)

Tags: bash, linux

A few days ago I posted a previous version of my first bash script here to get few tips and reviews so I could improve it. So now it is improved a bit. I also shellchecked it and fixed the warnings. I would love to hear more tips from you guys.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -r CONF_DIR_PATH="$HOME/.config/rdoc"
declare -r TMP_FILE="/tmp/rdoc_tmp.$$" 

#Trap the following signals and do cleanup before exiting 
trap 'rm -f "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null && exit 0' EXIT 
trap 'rm -f "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null && echo && exit 1' SIGINT

fn_generate_configs() {
    local doc_dir_path
    local pdf_viewer_name

    mkdir -p "$CONF_DIR_PATH"
    
    printf "Please enter your documents directory full path: "
    read -r doc_dir_path
    echo "$doc_dir_path" > "$CONF_DIR_PATH/doc_dir"

    printf "\nPlease enter your pdf's viewer name: "
    read -r pdf_viewer_name
    echo "$pdf_viewer_name" > "$CONF_DIR_PATH/pdf_viewer"

    printf "\nYour configurations were generated succesfully.\n"
}

fn_read_configs() {
    if ! doc_dir=$(cat "$CONF_DIR_PATH/doc_dir" 2> /dev/null); then
        echo Error: one or all of your configuration files are missing.
        echo Try -h for help.
        exit 1
    fi

    if ! pdf_viewer=$(cat "$CONF_DIR_PATH/pdf_viewer" 2> /dev/null); then
        echo Error: one or all of your configuration files are missing.
        echo Try -h for help.
        exit 1
    fi
}

fn_search_for_book() {
    local path
    local grep_opt="-q"
    local string_to_exclude="$1/"
    
    if [ "$i_status" -eq 1 ]; then 
        grep_opt="-qi"
    fi

    if [ "$r_status" -eq 1 ]; then #Search recursively  
        for path in "$1"/*; do  
            if [ -d "$path" ]; then 
                fn_search_for_book "$path"
            elif [ -f "$path" ]; then 
                #Redirect grep help message if book_name has the program's options value.
                #This would happen if the user called the program with the defualt behaviour,
                #plus with one of the available options but he/she omitted to pass the doc_name
                #so book_name will get the value of the passed options wich will trhow the grep help message.
                if echo "$path" | grep $grep_opt "$book_name" 2> /dev/null; then 
                    echo "${path//"$string_to_exclude"/}" >> "$TMP_FILE"
                fi
            fi
        done
    else
        for path in "$1"/*; do
            if [ -f "$path" ]; then 
                #Redirect grep help message for the same reasons as above
                if echo "$path" | grep $grep_opt "$book_name" 2> /dev/null; then 
                    echo "${path//"$string_to_exclude"/}" >> "$TMP_FILE"
                fi
            fi
        done

    fi
}

fn_display_books() {
    local doc
    local founded_docs
    
    #Make sure a book was founded and TMP_FILE was generated
    if ! founded_docs=$(cat "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null); then     
        printf "Error: no document was found with \'%s\' in it.\n" "$book_name"
        exit 1
    fi

    printf "These are the documents that were found:\n\n"
    #Set output's color to red
    tput setaf 1
    
    for doc in $founded_docs; do    
        echo "$doc"
    done

    #Reset output's color 
    tput sgr0 
}

fn_count_books() {
    local doc
    local founded_docs
    local cnt=0

    if ! founded_docs=$(cat "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null); then
        printf "\nError: \'%s\' manipulation while the program is running are disallowed.\n" "$TMP_FILE"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    for doc in $founded_docs; do 
        (( cnt++ ))
    done

    return "$cnt"
}

fn_final_book_name() {
    printf "\nWhich one of them would you like to open: "
    read -r book_name
}

fn_generate_books_paths() {
    local path
    
    if [ "$r_status" -eq 1 ]; then
        for path in "$1"/*; do
            if [ -d "$path" ]; then
                fn_generate_books_paths "$path"
            elif [ -f "$path" ]; then
                 echo "$path" >> "$TMP_FILE"
            fi
        done
    else 
        for path in "$1"/*; do
            if [ -f "$path" ]; then
                echo "$path" >> "$TMP_FILE"
            fi
        done
    fi
}

fn_get_book_path() {
    local founded_paths
    local path
    local grep_opt="-q"

    if ! founded_paths=$(cat "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null); then
        printf "\nError: \'%s\' manipulation while the program is running are disallowed.\n" "$TMP_FILE"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$i_status" -eq 1 ]; then
        grep_opt="-qi"
    fi

    for path in $founded_paths; do 
        if ! echo "$path" | grep $grep_opt "$book_name"; then 
            continue
        fi

        book_path="$path"
        break
    done
}

fn_open_book() {

    if ! "$pdf_viewer" "$book_path" 2> /dev/null; then 
        printf "\nError: %s can\'t be opened.\n" "$book_path" 
        exit 1
    fi

    printf "\nOpening: %s\n" "$book_path"
}

fn_help_message() {
printf "Usage: rdoc <options> [argument]
 
Available options:                                                                             
 -h               Display this help message.                                                   
 -g               Generate new configuration files.                                            
 -r               Allow recursive searching for the document.                                  
 -i               Ignore case distinctions while searching for the document.                   
 -s               Search for the document and display results.                                   
                  This option takes a document name or a part of it as an argument.            
 -o               Search for the document, display results then open it using your pdf viewer. 
                  This option takes a document name or a part of it as an argument.            
                  (Default)                                                                    
NOTE:                                                                                          
     When using '-s' or '-o' option in a combination of other options like this:               
                                                                                               
     $ rdoc -ris document_name                                                                 
                                                                                               
     Please make sure that it's the last option; to avoid unexpected behaviour.
"            
}


doc_dir=""
pdf_viewer=""
book_path=""
book_name=${!#} #book_name equals to the last arg by defualt so the default option ('-o') will work.

#Options status
r_status=0
i_status=0
s_status=0
o_status=1 #Make -o the default option 

#Display help message if no options were passed 
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    fn_help_message
    exit 0
fi

while getopts ":hgris:o:" opt; do
    case $opt in 
        h)
            fn_help_message
            exit 0
            ;;
        g)
            fn_generate_configs
            o_status=0
            ;;
        r)
            r_status=1
            ;;
        i)
            i_status=1
            ;;
        s)
            book_name="$OPTARG"
            s_status=1
            o_status=0 
            ;;
        o)
            book_name="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        :)
            printf "Error: an argument is required for \'-%s\' option.\n" "$OPTARG"
            echo Try -h for help.
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            printf "Error: unknown option \'-%s\'.\n" "$OPTARG"
            echo Try -h for help.
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$s_status" -eq 1 ]; then
    fn_read_configs
    fn_search_for_book "$doc_dir"
    fn_display_books
elif [ "$o_status" -eq 1 ]; then 
    fn_read_configs
    fn_search_for_book "$doc_dir"
    fn_display_books
    fn_count_books
    if [ $? -gt 1 ]; then #If more than 1 book were found with $book_name in it
        fn_final_book_name
        #Clean any leftovers of $TMP_FILE to search properly
        rm "$TMP_FILE" 2> /dev/null
        #Make sure that the user chose an available document
        fn_search_for_book "$doc_dir"
        if [ ! -f "$TMP_FILE" ]; then 
            printf "\nError: no document was found with \'%s\' in it.\n" "$book_name"
            exit 1
        fi

        #Make sure that the user is specific enough about the book name
        fn_count_books
        if [ $? -gt 1 ]; then
            printf "\nError: More than 1 book was found with the name \'%s\' in it.\n" "$book_name"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    
    : > "$TMP_FILE" #Make sure $TMP_FILE is empty so it'll be usable in fn_generate_books_paths
    fn_generate_books_paths "$doc_dir"
    fn_get_book_path
    fn_open_book
fi

exit 0
```

Here is a link to the repo on github for the ones who would prefer to review it there:
https://github.com/yankh764/rdoc

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Good

- nice indentation
- good docs for the options
- good variable names
- a reasonable amount of inline comments
- yay for being on top of the shellcheck already

## Suggestions

- For conditionals it is safer to use double square brackets.  Some folks on here discourage the double square brackets for portability, but bash/zsh/ksh all support the more modern syntax.
- Put your config into the format of a script and then [source it](https://superuser.com/a/46146/358509).
- Put your usage function near the top and include a line that says what the
  gist of the command is.

## Nits

These are minor issues that are more matters of taste.

- I wouldn't proceed every function with the same `fn_`, but I can see that might make it easier to keep a script of this size straight in your head.
- Putting a space after the hash in a comment will make it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for such a great review. I was surprised that you also included the good things alongside to the tips and suggestions which is really nice and encouraging, so I appreciate it. Lastly I will of course learn from your tips and modify my script to improve it :)